# What's a quickfix window and how to use it?

Tags: vim, vimgrep

I just found out how to use `vimgrep` command to search for a particular string in multiple files. I know that the search results are stored in **quickfix**

I use `:cnext` to go to the next matching pattern. But this is not a feasible option if there are hundreds of search results.

Can someone please explain how to use quickfix?

Comment: Try `:help quickfix`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quickfix list is a list of entries containing position, file, and message. It often used for searches like `:vimgrep` and `:grep` as well as finding errors via `:make`.

Here are a few quickfix list commands to get you up and running fast:

- Use `:cnext` and `:cprev` to move between your errors/matches.
- `:cfirst` and `:clast` to go to the first and last error/matches respectively.
- `:copen` to open up the quickfix list in a window (`:cclose` to close)
- `:cwindow` to open quickfix list window only if there are errors
- `:cc` to display the current error/match.
- May want to use better mappings for `:cnext` and friends. I suggest Tim Pope's [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin

For more help see the following:

```
:h quickfix
:h :cnext
:h :cfirst
:h :cope
:h :cwindow
:h :cc
```

Answer (score -1):

If one reads through :help quickfix, the answer to all your questions becomes readily apparent.

For a specific section of the help doc, try :help quickfix-window.

To open a quickfix window, which will show all the results, run the command

```
:copen
```

Which, can be shortened to

```
:cope
```